# Can't find android.jar in AppData

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm getting this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2,2): Error: Could not find android.jar for API Level 21. This means the Android SDK platform for API Level 21 is not installed. Either install it in the Android SDK Manager (Tools > Open Android SDK Manager...), or change your Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is installed. (C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar missing.) (Camera2Basic)
```

When I went to my AppData I could not find any folder called android in any of the folders which is why this error is occuring.

Comment: Try installing Android SDK Platform API 21 from the SDK as explained here: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/ide/launch_sdk_manager/

Comment: Yes I have already done that

Comment: Where does your Android SDK Manager download its packages?